# Why do people use Type *var instead of Type* var?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaring pointers; asterisk on the left or right of the space between the type and name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660633/declaring-pointers-asterisk-on-the-left-or-right-of-the-space-between-the-type)
>   [Does it matter where I place the asterisk when declaring pointers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449908/does-it-matter-where-i-place-the-asterisk-when-declaring-pointers-in-c)

I searched, but my keywords don't seem to fit. I'm pretty sure this question has already been asked., so point me in some direction if you know a link or something !

My question is, why do so many people use

```
TypeIdentifier *varname;
```

Instead of

```
TypeIdentifier* varname;
```

which is much more logical to me as the `*` modifies the type and not the variable name.

Comment: Please use the search before asking new questions - this has been asked and answered *numerous* times on SO.

Comment: Man, I have to train my keyword skills. Thanks for the link. @mekici Yes, it does. Well, I do. It sometimes really confuses me and I have to take a close look what type this variable exactly is.

Comment: Stroustrup recommends `Type* name` instead of `Type *name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both C and C++, the declaration syntax (mostly) follows usage.

The declaration

```
int *n;
```

can be read as "`n` is of type `int*`", or as "`*n` is of type `int`".  And if you take a look at the language grammar, the latter corresponds more closely to the way it's parsed.

For a type consisting of just a name (like `int`) and a `*`, it doesn't make a whole lot of difference, but it matters for more complex declarations.

The usual tendency is to use `int *n;` in C and `int* n;` in C++.  The latter is because that's Stroustrup's personal preference.  His point, I think, is that the "`n` is of type `int*`" reading is more natural, and the complexities can be avoided by not writing complex declarations.  For example, whichever spacing you prefer, it's better to write

```
int *a;
int b;
```

than either

```
int* a, b;
```

or

```
int *a, b;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of C's declaration syntax.

```
int* a, b;
```

looks as if it defined two variables of type `int*`, but actually declares `a` as type `int*` and `b` as type `int`. If you write

```
int *a, b;
```

this is obvious. I personally however prefer to just not write such a definition, but instead write

```
int* a;
int b;
```

which leaves no doubt about the types.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the syntax of language says otherwise. You can easily check it by

```
Type * var1, var2;
```

What will happen here?

Answer (score 1):

The C convention is to attach the `*` to the variable, because multiple variables in a row don't share the `*`:

```
int *a, b; /* a is an int*, while b is an int. */
```

In C++, the rules are the same, but it is more common to attach the wart to the type, due to the confusing nature of the above declaration, and the consequent practice of declaring only one variable per declaration:

```
int* a;
int b;
```

I lean towards the C++ convention, but also allowing multiple non-pointer-or-reference declarations on one line:

```
int a, b;
int* c;
int* d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because K&R used `Foo *bar` and people stuck with it.