# Don't understand a reference to a struct in 'C': (regs_t*) cntl->addr

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm reviewing C-code which contains the line,

```
volatile uart_regs_t* const regs = (uart_regs_t*) cntl->addr
```

I'm not familiar with syntax that places a '*' adjacent and to the right of a struct alias (`uart_regs_t`). Someone explain the pieces of this statement?

Comment: `(uart_regs_t*)` is a cast, it tells the compiler to treat `cntl->addr` as a pointer of `uart_regs_t`.

Comment: [Someone close as dupe of canonical type casting question please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558837/what-exactly-is-a-type-cast-in-c-c).

Comment: I found the answer I was looking for in another post:

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not familiar with syntax that places a '*' adjacent and to the right of a struct alias (`uart_regs_t`). Someone explain the pieces of this statement?

This syntax is explicit casting. It is used when the type of an expression is different than the type of the variable to be assigned to.

Type of `regs` is `volatile uart_regs_t* const`. Unless the type of `cntl->addr` can be implicitly converted to that type, you'll have to use the explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another post,

[Is there a convention for pointer declarations in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947260/is-there-a-convention-for-pointer-declarations-in-c)

The answer is these three syntaxes are the same, and are all type declarations:

```
int*  ptr;
int  *ptr;
int * pt;
```